# Can't success ./configure on CentOS 7: configure: error: You seem to be running X, but no X development libraries

Tags: install

CentOS 7

I want to install Emacs 26.3 on CentOS.
Here instruction
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Installing-Emacs.html

1. Download Emacs 26.3 from here https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/
2. Extract from archive like this.

   tar -zxvf emacs-26.3.tar.gz
3. `cd emacs-26.3`
4. `./configure`

But I get error:

```
...
checking for struct ifreq.ifr_netmask... yes
checking for struct ifreq.ifr_broadaddr... yes
checking for struct ifreq.ifr_addr... yes
checking for struct ifreq.ifr_addr.sa_len... no
checking whether gcc understands -MMD -MF... yes
checking for X... no
checking for X... true
configure: error: You seem to be running X, but no X development libraries
were found.  You should install the relevant development files for X
and for the toolkit you want, such as Gtk+ or Motif.  Also make
sure you have development files for image handling, i.e.
tiff, gif, jpeg, png and xpm.
If you are sure you want Emacs compiled without X window support, pass
  --without-x
to configure.
```

Comment: You will need to do something like `yum install libx11-devel` as well as a dozen or more `-devel` packages. Every time your configure fails, you are going to have to identify which `-devel` package to install.

Comment: Please do not post the same question on StackOverflow and emacs.SE. Choose one to keep and delete the other. Thx.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://gist.github.com/harrifeng/a3ebd9a2af4c65cacfd4

Comment: @FranBurstall Thanks. It's help. Now I has Emacs 25.1.1. on CentOS 7

Comment: This help me - https://justyn.io/til/compile-emacs-27-on-centos-7/ . Now I has Emacs 27.1 on CentOS 7